# Why does a rotating aluminium disc slow down when a current carrying coil with iron core is held above it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electromagnetic-induction

What  I don't understand is it the Emf induced that slows down the disc or is it a force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The induced EMF in the disc produces a current - an eddy current.  The current in the the magnetic field gives rise to a force that, in accordance with Lenz's law, opposes the inducing action.

Answer (score 1):

If a conductor moves through a magnetic field and an emf is induced.
If there is a conducting circuit then the induced emf produces an induced current.
Lenz's law, which is a consequence of the law of conservation of energy, says that the induced current will be such as to oppose the motion producing it which the rotation of the disc.
To produce the induced current a force is applied on the disc in opposition to its motion.
The kinetic energy of the disc decreases and that energy becomes heat idue to ohmic heating of the aluminium produced by the induced currents.